# Pandas read_csv not reading raw string

Tags: python, pandas, windows, unicode-escapes

I'm encountering an issue with my Python program that reads data from a CSV. I receive the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 125262-125263: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

The line that this error occurs:

```
self.df = pd.read_csv(spreadsheet_path, encoding='unicode_escape')
```

The variable `spreadsheet_path` is a string that contains the path of the CSV file – it's a raw string (i.e., the path is `r'C:\...'`). I have also tried double slashes.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of your csv file to be sure you're using the correct thing for `encoding=`?

Comment: I have encodeing='unicode_escape'. Is there something I should look for specifically in the CSV?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the filename, it's complaining about the contents of the file.

Comment: Show the line of the file that contains bytes 125262-125263.

Comment: It sounds like the file contains `\u` followed by something that isn't a valid Unicode escape.

Comment: [Here's a list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) of possible string encodings, it's going to depend on what the codec csv file file was encoded with, and whether it's not malformed

Comment: It probably needs to be `\\u`

Comment: How can I go in and see the lines with the specific bytes?

Comment: Also, it was encoded with ANSI

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mre].

Comment: Ok, so I can confirm the issue was there was a line with a "\u" in it. What can be done to get around this?